# How do you create start time & end time time pickers from preferences?

Tags: android, dialog, persistent, timepicker, listpreference

I would like to set up a time picker in a preference screen and allow the user to pick both a start time and also an end time and store it as a persistant value like other settings.

Could you show all the coding needed to set this up because I couldn't find anything like that by searching.

I'm thinking maybe the time picker should be in a dialog but I don't yet know how to set those up yet. If you can show coding that calls a dialog with a start and end time time picker and how to save that information for later retrieval from a preferences screen that would be great.

All help will be greatly appreciated.

Truly,
Emad

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a simple [`TimePreference`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-lunchlist/blob/master/19-Alarm/LunchList/src/apt/tutorial/TimePreference.java) that I use in one of my books:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.preference.DialogPreference;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class TimePreference extends DialogPreference {
  private int lastHour=0;
  private int lastMinute=0;
  private TimePicker picker=null;

  public static int getHour(String time) {
    String[] pieces=time.split(":");

    return(Integer.parseInt(pieces[0]));
  }

  public static int getMinute(String time) {
    String[] pieces=time.split(":");

    return(Integer.parseInt(pieces[1]));
  }

  public TimePreference(Context ctxt, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(ctxt, attrs);

    setPositiveButtonText("Set");
    setNegativeButtonText("Cancel");
  }

  @Override
  protected View onCreateDialogView() {
    picker=new TimePicker(getContext());

    return(picker);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onBindDialogView(View v) {
    super.onBindDialogView(v);

    picker.setCurrentHour(lastHour);
    picker.setCurrentMinute(lastMinute);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
    super.onDialogClosed(positiveResult);

    if (positiveResult) {
      lastHour=picker.getCurrentHour();
      lastMinute=picker.getCurrentMinute();

      String time=String.valueOf(lastHour)+":"+String.valueOf(lastMinute);

      if (callChangeListener(time)) {
        persistString(time);
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected Object onGetDefaultValue(TypedArray a, int index) {
    return(a.getString(index));
  }

  @Override
  protected void onSetInitialValue(boolean restoreValue, Object defaultValue) {
    String time=null;

    if (restoreValue) {
      if (defaultValue==null) {
        time=getPersistedString("00:00");
      }
      else {
        time=getPersistedString(defaultValue.toString());
      }
    }
    else {
      time=defaultValue.toString();
    }

    lastHour=getHour(time);
    lastMinute=getMinute(time);
  }
}
```

A production-grade implementation of this would use string resources for the two button captions. It might also have a bit more error checking on the value, in case some code updates it via `SharedPreferences.Editor` and does not format it properly.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I will experiment with it and try to figure out how it works.

At least I will find out how to lay out a dialog screen and call it TimePreference so your code with work with it.

Truly,
Emad

Comment: Hi, I've been searching for a long time to find an example setting.xml file showing the start time and end time items that have that nice circle with down pointing arrow in it but can't find anything. Do you have some sample code showing how to set that up? 
Thanks.
Truly,
Emad

Comment: @Emad-ud-deen: I have no idea what you are talking about, sorry.

Comment: Hi CommonsWare, 
I'm quite new to Android programming and Java so I think I need help in setting up the other files such as maybe a xml file with the layout xml file you used for the buttons etc. from the TimePreference class. Also do I need to add anything in the manifest files as well? Can you also tell me how to call this class within my preference activity. Thanks. Truly, Emad

Comment: Thanks for this code. One thing I suggest you add: in order to get default values to work, you need to `persistString(time);` in `protected void onSetInitialValue(){}`. Drove me crazy trying to figure out why `PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues()` wasn't working! My modifications: https://gist.github.com/nickaknudson/5024416